# Activate flag only for specific imported module in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I am trying to follow the instructions shown here: https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/3.0.html#porting-to-python-3-0

Specifically, "Turn on the -3 command line switch".

It is regarding Abaqus, which uses Python 2 but will use Python 3 in the next version, so I need to adjust my scripts. Therefore I want to turn on deprecation warnings for my scripts which I import, but only for my scripts and not the entire program.

Can I have the -3 flag be active only for the modules I am importing? Either by passing it as a parameter to the import statement, or by adding a command into the scripts I am importing.

I have checked the Python 2.7 documentation on Modules ( https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html ) and I did not see any way to modify the import statement.

I have also tried:
warnings.warn("deprecated", FutureWarning); import types; types.StringType

types.StringType does not exist in Python 3, so I was hoping to get a warning out of this statement, though no warning was produced. Same effect with DeprecationWarning and PendingDeprecationWarning.